# Filtering out inputs to textfile

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am using and Raspberry Pi (running raspbian) and I have a shellscript continuously outputting values into textfile via this command:

```
wavemon -d |grep -i signal >> textfile.txt
```

The output is as shown below:

```
signal level: 20 dBm (100.00mW)
```

Question: How can I remove the other words (**signal level: dBm (100.00mW)**) and just input the number into the textfile so the textfile only shows the number (20)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
wavemon -d | grep -oP 'signal level: \K[0-9]+'
```

- `-o` prints only the matching part
- `-P` activates Perl-compatible regular expressions PCRE (`\K`)
- `signal level: \K[0-9]+` search for the pattern `signal level:`, then \K resets the beginning of the match to the current position, and `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` program this way:

```
cat textfile.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Here is how it works:

First split your text `signal level: 20 dBm (100.00mW)` on delimiter "colon" with option `-d':'` and take the second field with option `-f2`.

Then split the result `20 dBm (100.00mW)` on delimiter "space" and take the second field again.

Comment: `cut` knows how to operate on files, so you don't need to use `cat` there

Comment: Thanks, it worked! By the way, is it possible to write a csv file from a shell script?

Comment: @EricRenouf: it's true, but I like it like that ;-) (separation of concerns)

Comment: @JolyDroneSP: a CSV file is a text file, so yes. Feel free to post another question on stackoverflow on that subject.

Comment: `cat` is for concatenating things. You don't concatenate anything. `< textfile.txt cut ...` isn't less separating concerns, but it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` for this, assuming the fields are all reliable:

```
wavemon -d | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1 ~ /signal/ {print $3}' >> textfile.txt
```

or if you want to just filter that file as it was already created

```
cut -f3 -d " " textfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed extract the first number from each line:

```
wavemon -d | sed 's/^[^0-9]\+ \([0-9]\+\) .*$/\1/'
```

Where `^` matches the start of a line, `$` the end of a line and `\1` is placeholder whatever is matches inside `\(\)`. The expression `[^0-9]` means match any character but a digit.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are on raspberry pi ,You can do it the python way.

```
import re
w=open("newfile.txt",'w')
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    a=re.findall(r'\d+',f.readline())
    w.write(a[0])
```